# ethtool flow control steer igmp packets

Tags: ethernet

I am attempting to explicitly steer igmp packets to the kernel via ethtool.

```
   ethtool -U ens1f0 flow-type ip4 l4proto 2 action 0
   rmgr: Cannot insert RX class rule: Protocol not supported
```

Doing any protocol (tcp4, udp4) returns the same results.  I have enabled ntuple-filters on the interface. Output of --show-features is:

```
ethtool --show-features ens1f0
Features for ens1f0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: on
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ipv6: on
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off [fixed]
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: on
rx-vlan-offload: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: on
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off [fixed]
rx-all: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
busy-poll: on [fixed]
```

Any thoughts on what is preventing me from adding this rule?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to ensure that igmp packets are steered to the kernel:

```
ethtool -U $A_INTERFACE flow-type ether dst 01:00:5e:00:00:01 action 0
ethtool -U $A_INTERFACE flow-type ether dst 01:00:5e:00:00:16 action 0
```

The destination mac addressed are constant igmp multicast destinations.

To map multicast address to MAC address see:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957928.aspx

> To map an IP multicast address to a MAC-layer multicast address, the
>   low order 23 bits of the IP multicast address are mapped directly to
>   the low order 23 bits in the MAC-layer multicast address. Because the
>   first 4 bits of an IP multicast address are fixed according to the
>   class D convention, there are 5 bits in the IP multicast address that
>   do not map to the MAC-layer multicast address. Therefore, it is
>   possible for a host to receive MAC-layer multicast packets for groups
>   to which it does not belong. However, these packets are dropped by IP
>   once the destination IP address is determined.
>
> For example, the multicast address 224.192.16.1 becomes
>   01-00-5E-40-10-01. To use the 23 low order bits, the first octet is
>   not used, and only the last 7 bits of the second octet is used. The
>   third and fourth octets are converted directly to hexadecimal numbers.
>   The second octet, 192 in binary is 11000000. If you drop the high
>   order bit, it becomes 1000000 or 64 (in decimal), or 0x40 (in
>   hexadecimal). For the next octet, 16 in hexadecimal is 0x10. For the
>   last octet, 1 in hexadecimal is 0x01. Therefore, the MAC address
>   corresponding to 224.192.16.1 becomes 01-00-5E-40-10-01.